# Bind to DialogResult failed

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm

I have a WPF Window that is meant to be used as a dialog. I am trying to use MVVM and have a view model as the DataContext of this dialog. So the simple confirmation dialog looks like:

```
<Window x:Class="Provision.Views.ConfirmationDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Provision.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ConfirmationDialog" Height="450" Width="800"
        DialogResult="{Binding DialogResult, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Content ="{Binding Resources.Ok, FallbackValue=Ok}" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding OkCommand}" Margin="12,0" Padding="12,6"/>
            <Button Content ="{Binding Resources.Cancel, FallbackValue=Cancel}" IsCancel="True" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Padding="12,6"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Resources.Confirmation, FallbackValue='Are you sure?'}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The problem I am having is binding to `DialogResult`. I get an error message

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'DialogResult' property of type 'ConfirmationDialog'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'
```

The property in the view model that it is binding to looks like:

```
private bool _dialogResult = false;
public bool DialogResult
{
    get => _dialogResult;
    set
    {
        if (_dialogResult != value)
        {
            _dialogResult = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I would eventually like to do something like

```
var result = new ConfirmationDialog().ShowDialog()
```

But I guess I don't understand the error message or how to overcome it. Can I make it a `DependencyProperty` in the view model? If so how?

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox?view=net-5.0

Comment: Wrap the message box behind a service abstraction to avoid mixing UI concerns

Comment: @Nkosi This is a simplified version of more complicated dialogs than `MessageBox`. Admittedly as is it does the same thing.

Comment: @Nkosi It is unclear to me from the documentation that `MessageBox` handles localization.

Comment: Since you control the text displayed in the message box, then you can handle localizations when populating it.

Comment: But I don't see that I can control the text of the buttons

Comment: You should not bind to the `DialogResult`. You should set it. The `ConfirmationDialog` doesn't bind to the view model.